# Suggest a name for a class which has an expiry time

Tags: c#, java, naming

> "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache
>   invalidation and naming things" - Phil Karlton.

I am writing a class which wraps an object with an expiry timestamp.

The API looks like this:

```
class ObjectWrapperWithExpiry<T> {
  private T obj; 
  private long expiryTimestamp; 


  ObjectWrapperWithExpiry(T obj, int ttl) {
    this.obj = obj; 
    expiryTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() + ttl * 1000;
  }

  T value() {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() > expiryTimestamp) return null; 
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Any suggestion on the class name?

Answer (score 3):

Expiring

If you use it in code it will read like this:

```
Expiring<String> str;
```

telling you that it is a string that expires :)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [References](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html) in Java. So maybe something like TimedReference.

Edit: You could probably even extend Reference(in Java) and enable the whole notification and Queue stuff aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just name it

timeStamp

TS

tStamp

.....Really it could even be named GiantHippo, its not going to change anything as long as you and another developer know what it does and why its there.

Comment: agree about the not going to change anything, but still not too happy with the current name, looks a bit dumb ...

Comment: Yeah, but the proper name is important for a class. Naming it wrong will create issues for years to come. More developers that use it=more issues. Names are important.

“The beginning of wisdom is to call things by their right names”--chinese proverb
Although I do like GiantHippo

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like ExpirableObject or even EpirarableWrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should be an adverb.  How about Expirable?

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeStampExpiryObj
```

I liked the quote you posted by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I once used `Transient<T>` for this type of class.

Answer (score 0):

BecomesNullEventually?
TimesOut?